# Issue on mouse hover between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I keep the `#panel` slide down/open when mouse traveling/hovering between  `#flip` and `#panel`? And how slide up only when mouse is out of these two?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#flip").hover(function() {
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
  }, function() {});
  $("#panel").hover(function() {

  }, function() {
    $(this).slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And how slide up only when mouse is out of these two?

In order to achieve this result you need to:

- show the panel (slideDown) when mouse enters the panel or the flip and the panel is hidden
- hide the panel (slideUp) when mouse leaves the panel or the flip and the panel is visible. Here, the selector should be :not(#flip, #panel)

```js
$("#flip, #panel").on('mouseenter', function (e) {
  if ($("#panel").is(':hidden')) { // this test in order to reduce useless slideDown....
      $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
  }
});
$(":not(#flip, #panel)").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if ($("#panel").is(':visible')) { // this test in order to reduce useless slideUp....
      $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#panel,
#flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you add a `#container` around `#flip` and `#panel`
you can add a `.mouseleave()` event to it, so when you click on `#flip` the panel slides down (and expand the container), as long as you keep the mouse inside that container the panel stays open (you can hover on flip or panel). When the mouse leaves the container the panel slide back up.

(I changed the event you had on flip to a click event as well as it says "click to slide")

as a tip, you might want to refacor your code to use CSS classes instead of id, this would make your code reusable (you could have multiple sliding pannel in the same page)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#container").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
  <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```